# Jupyter (.vsix) installation on vscode failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Received the following message while trying to install Jupyter vsix file on Windows 10, all other packages includying Python seem install fine:

```
toolsai.jupyter-2023.7 not compatible with vs code 1.80.1
```

The file was downloaded directly from ms site:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Appreciate the help!

Comment: interestingly, the pre-release version of the extension is currently `v2023.7.1001901100`. I have VS Code 1.80.1, and the pre-release version seems to have installed just fine.

Comment: Thank you starball! Tried your answer and worked like a charm!